# Remove extra spaces from a string without using Regex or any internal library methods

Tags: c#, .net, strings, algorithm

The objective is to remove extra spaces from the below string:

> `"   Today   it  is     going    to  rain.     "`

so it looks like below

> `"Today it is going to rain."`

Please determine if the code will perform well and if there is a better solution (NO REGEX or LAMBDA).

```
static string CompactStringPerfect()
{  
    string longString = "   Today   it  is     going    to  rain.     ";  

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] longChars = longString.ToCharArray();

    int spaceCount = 0;

    //Using standard method with no library help
    for (int i = 0; i < longChars.Length; i++)
    {
        //If space then keep a count and move on until nonspace char is found
        if (longChars[i] == 32)
        {
            spaceCount++;
            continue;
        }

        //If more than one space then append a single space  
        if (spaceCount > 1 && sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append(" ");

        //Append the non space character
        sb.Append(longChars[i]);

        //Reset the space count
        spaceCount = 1;
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: so https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: Minor thought: what about tabs in the string '\t'?

Comment: There are no tabs in the string

Comment: I have to ask... why exactly is it a requirement that possible solutions not use regex or linq? You're excluding possibly good solutions and it's important that we understand why. (Perhaps it's actually more important that *you* understand why.)

Answer (score 3):

A few things to point out.

> ```
> char[] longChars = longString.ToCharArray();
> ```

`string`s in C# are array-like, and can be indexed directly. We don't need to convert it into a `char[]`.

> ```
> int spaceCount = 0;
> ```

We don't really need to keep track of *how many* spaces so much as whether the last character was a space. Therefore, this can become a boolean flag instead.

> ```
> if (longChars[i] == 32)
> ```

This line has a magic number (`32`), and that makes it a little harder to understand. I'm guessing it's the Unicode number for the space character, but the fact that I have to guess makes it bad. Better would be: `if(longChars[i] == ' ')`, but best would be: `if(Char.IsWhiteSpace(longChars[i]))`. That catches **all** potential whitespace characters, and will be more robust. Also, it makes your intention much clearer.

> ```
> if (spaceCount > 1 && sb.Length > 0)
>     sb.Append(" ");
> ```

I always recommend using braces in light of [goto fail](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html).

> ```
> //Reset the space count
> spaceCount = 1;
> ```

This confuses me. You say you are "resetting" the space count, but the original value was `0`, not `1`, so I might (incorrectly) think this is a bug and try to fix it. The root of this issue lies in how you are tracking spaces.

So incorporating those suggestions, here's what I come up with:

```
public static string Despace(string longString) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool lastWasSpace = true; // True to eliminate leading spaces

    for(int i = 0; i < longString.Length; i++) {
        if(Char.IsWhiteSpace(longString[i]) && lastWasSpace) {
            continue;
        }

        lastWasSpace = Char.IsWhiteSpace(longString[i]);

        sb.Append(longString[i]);
    }

    // The last character might be a space
    if(Char.IsWhiteSpace(sb[sb.Length - 1])) {
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()`, and then go over the `String` array you got. If some variable is not " ", it's a word like you need.

```
public class RemoveExtraSpacesFromString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = " Today it is going to rain. ";        
        String strResult = "Today it is going to rain.";

        if (compactStringPerfect(str).equals(strResult)){
            System.out.println("Good Job!");
        }
    }

    private static String compactStringPerfect(String spacesStr){

        String newStr = "";
        String currentStr = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < spacesStr.length(); /*no incrementation*/) {
            if (spacesStr.charAt(i) != ' '){
                while (spacesStr.charAt(i) != ' '){
                    currentStr += spacesStr.charAt(i); 
                    i++;
                }               
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }
            if (!currentStr.equals("")){
                newStr += currentStr + " ";
                currentStr = "";
            }
        }

        return newStr.trim();

    }

}
```

Comment: Cannot use any internal string manipulation functions....

Comment: So it's only a way of find words with while loop and adding them to a new string separated by spaces

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: I updated my answer with code

Comment: Roey, Thanks for the java code. I think splitting the string into words is the optimal way but for some reason the interviewer did not want me to use any library string manipulation functions...

Comment: Maybe the interviewer was meant that you will implement it using some recursion?

Comment: Also, what does it means: "not want me to use any library string manipulation functions" ?  is `charAt()` and `length()` included?

Comment: No, they asked me not to use trim(), split() or regex. I think your java solution is good but they wanted me to write code in c# so i posted my code to make sure it is optimal or if there is a better version in terms of time and space.

Comment: I know that `trim()` is a bad solution in my code just make `substring()` over there and it's the same, also, `trim()` is removing spaces on the side, and not in the middle of the `String`

Comment: in c# strings are immutable so cannot use substring.... I think c++ or java handles string manipulation elegantly ... anyways, just wanted to share this and see if i am on the right track...... i will try to write a function to do this recursively......

Comment: strings are immutable also in java, but each recusrsion iteration you can return a string which concats to the one before

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to remove extra spaces. In Java, it would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "      Today   it  is     going    to  rain.     ";
    String strResult = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();

    System.out.println(strResult);
}
```

**Output:**

> Today it is going to rain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for sharing your insight. I think using regex is the fastest and optimal solution to this. I believe this was an interview question just to see how one codes and things if no helper functions were to be used.

Another simple way of doing this is

```
...
char[] WhiteSpace = new char[] { ' ' };
string longString = "   Today   it  is     going    to  rain.     ";
string[] split = longString.Split(WhiteSpace, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string compactedString = string.Join(" ", split);
...
```